# Deriving the general equation of ellipses in cartesian form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Given, the equation of a Cartesian circle is given in this general formula: $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$. This can be derived from the distance formula and Pythagoras's Theorem. However, how can I derive the general formula of an ellipse: $\frac{(x-a)^2}{c} + \frac{(y+b)^2}{d} = 1$ ?

Comment: Take a circle and stretch one axis. The formula you have is not most general as you can also rotate an ellipse.

Comment: perhaps it might be good to include what do you think an ellipse is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equation

Comment: This depends on the definition of an ellipse you use. By the way your formula is not the general one. It describes only the ellipses with axes parallel to the coordinate ones.